# Spring MVC @ControllerAdvice exception behavior different based on Exception source

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

Depending on whether a DuplicateKeyException (DKE) is thrown by the call to the NamedParameterJdbcTemplate (i.e. jdbcTemplate.update(sql, namedParameter)) or explicitly thrown by me in the code, the behavior is very different.

When the DKE is thrown by the jdbcTemplate call, the correct behavior happens. My @ControllerAdvice kicks in and the correct HTTP status and ResponseBody is returned. But when I explicitly throw the DKE, a 500 error is returned to the client, even though I see that the correct block of code in my @ControllerAdvice class is being reached.

Here's the code to handle the exception, which should always return HttpStatus.OK along with a RestError:

```
@ExceptionHandler(DuplicateKeyException.class)
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody RestError handleDuplicateKey(
    HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex) {     

    logger.error("GlobalExceptionHandler handling exception of type DuplicateKeyException.class: ", ex);
    return new RestError(HttpStatus.CONFLICT, 
                     ErrorCode.DUPLICATE_ENTRY, 
                     ex.getCause().getMessage());
    }
```

Here's the code that can throw a DKE:

```
public void insertSubscriber(SubscriberInfo subscriberInfo) {

    if (isAlreadySubscribed(subscriberInfo)) {
        // this will result in a 500 http error to the client
        throw new DuplicateKeyException(
            String.format("This subscriber is already subscribed");
    }

    String sql = "INSERT INTO subscribers (firstname, email, postal_code, subscriber_type) "
               + "VALUES (:firstname, :email, :postal_code, :subscriber_type)";

    HashMap<String, String> namedParameter = Maps.newHashMapWithExpectedSize(4);
    namedParameter.put("email", subscriberInfo.getEmail());
    namedParameter.put("postal_code", subscriberInfo.getPostalCode());
    namedParameter.put("subscriber_type", subscriberInfo.getUserType().getId());
    namedParameter.put("firstname", subscriberInfo.getFirstname());

    // if a DKE is thrown from the below line, everything works fine. 
    jdbcTemplate.update(sql, namedParameter);       
}
```

I'd really like to understand why the behavior is different based on where the exception comes from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you are just setting the msg inside DKE, whereas in exceptionhandler you are doing ex.getCause().getMessage() which I guess is throwing NPE. Try setting Throwable cause with a msg and give it a try.

Comment: So yea, this was a dumb mistake on my part. I'm somewhat disappointed that there was no indication of an NPE anywhere in the stack trace or debug info provided by Spring.

Comment: can you update the answer with the solution if possible, I am facing the same problem.